# Why email is not shown as a Json response in django rest api

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

View

```
class UserRegistrationView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserRegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
            response_data = {
                'token': token.key,
                'message': 'User registration successful.'
            }
            return Response(response_data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Serializer

```
class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    def validate_username(self, data):
        if User.objects.filter(username=data).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Username already exists.")
        return data
    
    def validate_email(self, data):
        if User.objects.filter(email=data).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Email already exists.")
        return data
```

url

```
    path('reg/',UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='userreg' )
```

in my post request i got only

`{ "username": [ "This field is required." ], "password": [ "This field is required." ] }`

In this serializer i passed the fields such as username password and email.. but i got only email and username as a json response why email is not showing as a json response.

Comment: What did you send to the `reg/` endpoint?

Comment: that registration here i just put it as a short form

Comment: But what did you put in the POST request? It looks like you sent an empty request

Answer (score 0):

Email is not showing in the Json Response as you are not sending email field in your **response_data** dict. You can add email like this:

```
class UserRegistrationView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserRegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
            response_data = {
                'token': token.key,
                'email': user.email,
                'message': 'User registration successful.'
            }
            return Response(response_data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

- It seems like you are sending empty object `{}` to post request, and checking for validation error.
- Validation error not coming for email because by default **django user model** sets required field to only username & password.
- so you have to extend AbstractUser, and replace django-inbuilt user model with customized one.

  ```
  from django.db import models
  from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
  from .user_manager import UserManager

  class User(AbstractUser):
    objects = UserManager()
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['email','password']
  ```